# New Whirlpool washing machine has locked door and non responsive buttons

Tags: washing-machine

I just installed a brand new Whirlpool front loading washing machine, Model number W10656476A. We put in our first load, pressed start, and realized we forgot to turn on the water supply lines.  We cleared the low water supply faults, but now the machine just makes a humming noise like a motor is running whenever it is plugged in, but not doing anything. The doors are locked and the buttons are non responsive.

What should I be doing?

Also, what size bit driver do I need to take the screws off of this thing to make sure the drain pump isn't clogged?

Comment: Did you turn on the water faucets behind the washing machine now? The statement "We cleared the low water supply faults" is not really informative as to if you actually turned in the those faucets.

Comment: Good point. We did turn on the faucets.

Comment: Unplug it, wait 5 minutes, plug it in. If no joy after that, call the manufacturer, and don't go voiding your warranty by poking where you should not...+1 to @keshlam - how the heck would your drain pump be clogged if you haven't put any water into the machine yet? And if it is clogged the first time you go to use it, that's utterly a warranty repair.

Comment: You removed the shipping bolts from the back I hope?

Comment: We did remove the shipping bolts. They were securing the power cord.

Comment: I had exact same issue here. May I know how did you get this fixed in the end? Thanks

Comment: Called a service tech, he opened up the top and had to reset the control board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check that you followed *all* the installation instructions in the manual, no matter how trivial they seem. If it still doesn't work after that, call the manufacturer; that's what warranties are for.

Re checking the pump: That is NOT a normal maintenance action. You should never need to do so, certainly not while it's still under warranty. If you have to ask, ***don't***.

Comment: I agree don't touch it.  I have dealt with Whirlpool and it is torture.  If you even mentioned that you started thinking about troubleshooting they start asking your questions to see if you voided the warranty.  Also note that many display and even repaired machines are repackaged as "new".  This isn't necessarily Whirlpool but mainly the stores.  I know Lowes is superb about making a package look new after customer returned something - bought a "used" (5 year old at least) shower valve that had shrink wrap around the box.

Answer (score 1):

We turned on the water then we unplugged the washer for a minute. Then we plugged it back in the door light was still on and still kept making that humming sound. After around 5-7 minutes the washing machine reset itself and we were able to open the door. The washing machine worked fine after that.

Comment: Did you have the same model of Whirlpool washer?

Answer (score 0):

The machine's on-board computer is confused.  Try this first: locate the "end of cycle notification" button on the front of the machine and hold it in for 5 seconds at least.

If that doesn't work, you can try unplugging the machine from the outlet, waiting a minute, then plugging it back in.

Comment: I'll try pressing that button, but currently none of the buttons are responsive and the motor noise starts running as soon as I plug it in even after hours of being unplugged.

Comment: One last thing that occured to me.  My new washer came with plugs inside the inlets rather than caps over them.  I actually threaded one of my hoses on before I noticed. Are you sure nothing is blocking the water supply?

Comment: I'll check that out. I know the hoses at clear because i ran water through them. But I'll check the inlets.

Answer (score -2):

Your main PCB is bad. Unplug your water pressure switch and that should turn off the drain pump. Check your pressure switch; if that's OK, replace the main board.

Comment: Possible, but I don't think it can be stated that definitely, and if the machine is under warranty it's almost always better to make the manufacturer deal with it.